# What's the better way to write this linq query?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

**SQL**:

```
SELECT node.CategoryId, 
    node.CategoryName, 
    node.Description, 
    node.Lft, node.Rgt, 
    node.ShowOnMenu,
 (COUNT(parent.CategoryName) - 1) AS Level, 
 (CASE WHEN node.Lft = node.Rgt - 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END) AS Leaf
FROM Article_Category AS node,
Article_Category AS parent
WHERE node.Lft BETWEEN parent.Lft AND parent.Rgt
GROUP BY node.CategoryId,node.CategoryName,node.Description,node.Lft,node.Rgt,node.ShowOnMenu
ORDER BY node.Lft
```

**My linq expression**:

```
        var list = (from node in DbContext.Categories
                    from parent in DbContext.Categories
                    where node.Lft >= parent.Lft && node.Lft <= parent.Rgt
                    select new
                    {
                        node.CategoryId,
                        node.CategoryName,
                        node.Description,
                        node.Lft,
                        node.Rgt,
                        node.ShowOnMenu,
                        ParentName = parent.CategoryName,
                    } into x
                    group x by new
                    {
                        x.CategoryId,
                        x.CategoryName,
                        x.Description,
                        x.Lft,
                        x.Rgt,
                        x.ShowOnMenu,
                    } into g
                    orderby g.Key.Lft
                    select new
                    {
                        CategoryId = g.Key.CategoryId,
                        CategoryName = g.Key.CategoryName,
                        Description = g.Key.Description,
                        Lft = g.Key.Lft,
                        Rgt = g.Key.Rgt,
                        ShowOnMenu = g.Key.ShowOnMenu,
                        Level = g.Count() - 1,
                        IsLeaf = g.Key.Lft == g.Key.Rgt - 1
                    }).ToList();
```

**My question:**

1. The linq expression is too long, there is two 'select new' expressions, i wonder how to make it shorter?
2. What's the corresponding Extension Method to the linq query? How can i express the "from... from...where..." with Extension method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `select new .. into x` I don't see why you need, try removing it and write `group node by new...`

`"from...from"` is written as a lambda expression like this:

```
Categories.SelectMany(n => Categories, (n, p) => new { Node = n, Parent = p });
```

Comment: Now my first question is resolved, i remove the first 'select new', it works. But i still don't know how to write the corresponding extention method. Do i have to use '(u, c)=>' expression to select all properties i need, and then 'GroupBy','OrderBy', and 'Select new' again? If this, it's the same with my first question(two 'new').

Comment: @RongieZeng Updated answer to use the tables from you question.